# iOS Photo Upload to a server

Tags: ios, image, api, upload

I've been trying for days on how to upload an image to an API. There is a cURL example there like this.

```
curl "http://address.com/api/" -F "parameter[name]=My Upload" -F "parameter[description]=this is my upload" -F "parameter[other]=additional info" -F "parameter[image]=@wake_2560x1600.jpg;type=image/jpg"
```

How would I use this to upload to a server via an NSMutableURLRequest & NSURLConnection? I have tried a few different ways but have not succeeded. Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:

I'm currently trying out ASIFormDataRequest

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9);
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request addRequestHeader:@"User-Agent" value:@"iOS App"];
[request addPostValue:@"name" forKey:@"parameter[name]"];
[request addPostValue:@"description" forKey:@"parameter[description]"];
[request addPostValue:@"other" forKey:@"parameter[other]"];
[request addData:imageData withFileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"jpeg_%d.jpg", rand()] andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"param[image]"];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Answer (score 2):

Rough way of doing it.

PHP Script.

```
<?php
$target_path  = "./";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
 echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
 " has been uploaded";
} else{
 echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

IOS code

```
- (void)upload:(UIImage *)image {
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 80);
    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.upload.com/upload.php"; // URL of upload script.

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"test.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"returnString: %@", returnString);
}
```

Just make sure the variable name you use is the same, in here i use "uploadedfile" both for php and ioscode

php

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
```

ios

```
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"test.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

// although right now im using https://github.com/samvermette/SVHTTPRequest

if you import that library in your code then making upload would be as easy as this

```
[SVHTTPRequest POST:@"http://www.upload.com/upload.php"
            parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:imageData, @"uploadedfile", nil]
              progress:^(float progress) {
                  progressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Uploading (%.0f%%)", progress*100];
              }
            completion:^(id response, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                progressLabel.text = @"Upload complete";
            }];
```